# .htaccess SSL and Non SSL with www to non www redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, ssl, https

I've used various answers on here to create the .htaccess script below. What I need the script to do is

1) Redirect all www to non www (for example www.example.com to example.com)

2) lose the php at the end of a page (for example www.example.com/store.php to example.com/store)

3) Redirect all hits for a particular page to the secure HTTPS version (for example http://www.example.com/secure-page to https://example.com/secure-page)

I've managed to do everything above, with the exception of being able to redirect www to non www for https pages. The following is my code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L] 

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^secure-page\.php$ https://example.com/secure-page [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^secure-page/ secure-page [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^secure-page/ secure-page [R=301,L]
```

I've tried adding the line

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

But that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

0) RewriteEngine and Options :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
Options +FollowSymlinks +MultiViews
```

1) Redirect www to non-www :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

2) Use the `MultiViews` option.

3) Redirect to https :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^secure-page https://example.com/secure-page [L,R=301]
```